# How to draw Thai text to PDF file by using libharu library

Tags: libharu

i am using free pdf library libharu to generate PDF file,
but i have a encoding problem, i can not draw Thai lanugage text on PDF file,
all the text shows "???.."

Somebody know how to fix it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have succeeded in rendering hieroglyphic texts (not Thai, but Chinese and Japanese) using libharu. First of all, I used Unicode mode, please refer to **HPDF_UseUTFEncodings**() function documentation.

For C language, here is a sequence of libharu API calls needed to overcome your trouble:

```
HPDF_UseUTFEncodings(docHandle);
HPDF_SetCurrentEncoder(docHandle, "UTF-8");
```

Here `docHandle` is a valid `HPDF_Doc` object.

Next part is proper work with UTF fonts:

```
const char * libFontName = HPDF_LoadTTFontFromFile(docHandle, fontFileName.c_str(), font_embed::EmbedFonts);
HPDF_Font font = HPDF_GetFont(docHandle, libFontName, "UTF-8");
```

After these calls you may render unicode texts containing Thai characters. Also note about embedding flag (3rd param of LoadTTFontFromFile) - your PDF file may be unreadable due to external font references. If you are not crazy with output PDF size, you may just embed fonts.

I've tested couple of Thai .ttf fonts found in Google and they were rendered OK. Also (it may be important, but I'm not sure) I'm using fork of libharu https://github.com/kdeforche/libharu which is now merged into master branch.

Answer (score 0):

When you write text to the PDF, use the correct font and encoding. In the libharu documentation you have all the possibilities: https://github.com/libharu/libharu/wiki/Fonts

In your case, you must use the `ISO8859-11` `Thai, TIS 620-2569 character set`

An example (in spanish):

```
    HPDF_Font fontEn = HPDF_GetFont(pdf, "Helvetica-Bold", "ISO8859-2");
    HPDF_Page_TextOut(page1, 50.00, 750.00, [@"Código para correcta codificación en libharu" cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding]);
```